# Image won't show up on navigation bar

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm unable to get the image to show up and I'm not sure why. The link to the image IS correct, its inside my www folder and images with the same file path work when calling them as a background image, however just using a  tag wont work and displays a broken image. Here's the current code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; color: white;" href="#"><span style="font-weight: 600;"><img src="images/navlogo.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-right: 5px;">Rade</span>byte</a>
```

and here is what it displays:

[image: The result]

I've tried setting background images in the same place that work, however I have to have text for it to show up properly and its just buggy. But it refuses to get the image from the correct file path as shown here:

[image: Image showing the path]

So I'm not really sure why it won't show up. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your page tries to load the image based on the relative path, which is http://yourwebsite.com/images/navlogo.png.

But since the image is located in your theme folder, you should use [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) to return your theme directory URL:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/navlogo.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-right: 5px;">
```